# please explain this line of code mentioned below

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, data-science

First, the "clicks" dataframe is passed through the function "get_data_splits" which return train, valid and test. Further, it is passed through the train model.

```
clicks = clicks.join(interactions)
print("Score with interactions")
train, valid, test = get_data_splits(clicks)
_ = train_model(train, valid)
```

**Clue**: The first feature you'll be creating is the number of events from the same IP in the last six hours. It's likely that someone who is visiting often will download the app. Implement a function count_past_events that takes a Series of click times (timestamps) and returns another Series with the number of events in the last hour.
But I'm unable to comprehend these lines of code.

```
def count_past_events(series, time_window='6H'):
    series = pd.Series(series.index, index=series)
    past_events = series.rolling(time_window).count() - 1
    return past_events
```

Comment: please add details to your question. what don't you understand exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi and welcome to the forum! Sadly, that method you wrote does not work. The rolling method's time_window parameter defines the size of the moving window, but for **the number of observations** used for calculating the statistic. (See here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html).

.resample, on the other hand, is similar to .rolling but it's for time-based offsets. That's what you need! And you can use the dataframe directly. See a full example below:

```
#Create a sample DataFrame
df=pd.DataFrame([["1/1/2016 12:00:20 AM", 1],
                 ["1/2/2016 5:03:20 AM", 2],
                 ["1/2/2016 5:06:20 AM", 3],
                 ["1/2/2016 5:07:20 AM", 4],
                 ["1/2/2016 6:06:20 AM", 5],
                 ["1/3/2016 00:00:20 AM", 6]]
        ,columns=['date','event_id'])

#We convert the date column into datetime and set as the index
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df.index = df.date
del df['date']


#This is where the magic happens.    
df.resample('6H', label = 'right').count()
```

Let's explain the last line a little bit more. We are *downsizing* the DataFrame into six hours bins - that is, each row will represent six hours of data. For each row, we will *count* the number of data points there, and the *name* of each row will be the right edge of the bin. This is the output we get:

```
           date     
2016-01-01 06:00:00     1
2016-01-01 12:00:00     0
2016-01-01 18:00:00     0
2016-01-02 00:00:00     0
2016-01-02 06:00:00     3
2016-01-02 12:00:00     1
2016-01-02 18:00:00     0
2016-01-03 00:00:00     0
2016-01-03 06:00:00     1
```

As you can see, at 2016-01-02 06:00:00, there had been 3 events during the previous six hours.

Happy hacking! Please let me know if you have more doubts. And if you think this answered your question, please click the check mark at the left of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Although the current answer gives a nice workaround, it does not really explain how the code in the question works :

```
def count_past_events(series, time_window='6H'):
    series = pd.Series(series.index, index=series)
    past_events = series.rolling(time_window).count() - 1
    return past_events
```

Let's create a toy Series from the other question :

```
import pandas as pd
input_serie = pd.Series(["1/1/2016 12:00:20 AM",
                         "1/2/2016 5:03:20 AM",
                         "1/2/2016 5:06:20 AM",
                         "1/2/2016 5:07:20 AM",
                         "1/2/2016 6:06:20 AM",
                         "1/3/2016 00:00:20 AM"],
                         name='date',
                         dtype = 'datetime64[ns]'
                       )
```

It look like this :

```
0   2016-01-01 00:00:20
1   2016-01-02 05:03:20
2   2016-01-02 05:06:20
3   2016-01-02 05:07:20
4   2016-01-02 06:06:20
5   2016-01-03 00:00:20
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

And now we can  break it line by line :

```
series = pd.Series(series.index, index=series)
```

Given an input `Series` object, you build a new one, using the values of the input series as index of the new one. This is because by default the rolling window applies on the index.

`series` looks like this :

```
date
2016-01-01 00:00:20    0
2016-01-02 05:03:20    1
2016-01-02 05:06:20    2
2016-01-02 05:07:20    3
2016-01-02 06:06:20    4
2016-01-03 00:00:20    5
dtype: int64
```

On to the next line :

```
past_events = series.rolling(time_window).count() - 1
```

The `rolling` function is an aggregation applied to your DataFrame/Series that only take into account a finite number of lines or , in your case, a time frame.
Now that your Series index is a datetime, you can apply `rolling` on it, with `time_windows` of your choice (in your case, 6 hours), and you want the `count()` of events in that timeframe. The '-1' is just here to avoid counting the current event, and only count the past events.

The returned result looks like this :

```
date
2016-01-01 00:00:20    0.0 --> No event before
2016-01-02 05:03:20    0.0 --> first event of the day
2016-01-02 05:06:20    1.0 --> one event in the past 6 h
2016-01-02 05:07:20    2.0 --> two events in the past 6 h
2016-01-02 06:06:20    3.0 --> three events in the past 6 h
2016-01-03 00:00:20    0.0 --> next day, no event in the past 6 h
dtype: float64
```

I hope it's more clear for you.

Comment: nice explanation! but the rolling method doesn't accept '6H' as a parameter, right? that's why I needed to do the workaround.

Comment: Yes it does, if the index is a datetime type :). You can specify all kind of time interval, like days,seconds...

Comment: Yours should be the correct answer then. I thought the code didn't even work.